# Will a MiniHDMI to VGA adapter work to connect duel monitors with a GTX740?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have a GTX740 and it has 3 ports miniHDMI, DVI-I and DVI-D. One of the DVI ports doesn't seem to be working or its just I bought a faulty adaptor for it. But Im wondering if I buy a miniHDMI to a VGA adaptor will it work to connect my second monitor to my graphics card.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes MiniHDMI to VGA should work fine as it's what I use. In the case of the DVI port not working it could just be a faulty input or a faulty card.

Comment: Thanks man, I will probs get that adapter. I dont think that the card is faulty its quite new but you never know!

Comment: Yeah you never know, if that adapter doesn't work then you should RMA it